# django postgresql json field schema validation

Tags: json, django, postgresql, jsonschema

I have a django model with a `JSONField` (django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField)
Is there any way that I can validate model data against a json schema file?

(pre-save)
Something like `my_field = JSONField(schema_file=my_schema_file)`

Comment: @e4c5 it is an anti-pattern to write validation logic into a model's .save() method. Model validation should live in a model's validators and be called via Model.full_clean() BEFORE calling .save(). .save() should be called after validation checks have passed. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects  More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220104/what-is-the-proper-process-for-validating-and-saving-data-with-with-django-djang

Answer (score 40):

I wrote a custom validator using [`jsonschema`](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) in order to do this.

**`project/validators.py`**

```py
import django
from django.core.validators import BaseValidator
import jsonschema
    

class JSONSchemaValidator(BaseValidator):
    def compare(self, value, schema):
        try:
            jsonschema.validate(value, schema)
        except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError:
            raise django.core.exceptions.ValidationError(
                '%(value)s failed JSON schema check', params={'value': value}
            )
```

**`project/app/models.py`**

```py
from django.db import models

from project.validators import JSONSchemaValidator

MY_JSON_FIELD_SCHEMA = {
    'schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'my_key': {
            'type': 'string'
        }
    },
    'required': ['my_key']
}

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_json_field = models.JSONField(
        default=dict,
        validators=[JSONSchemaValidator(limit_value=MY_JSON_FIELD_SCHEMA)]
    )
```

Comment: For those who this did't work completely, i had to add this function Model.clean_fields() and then Model.save() depending on the change

Comment: If you have performance issues validating deeply nested JSON structures, see [`fastjsonschema`](https://github.com/horejsek/python-fastjsonschema). The speed up for us was incredible.

Answer (score 8):

That's what the `Model.clean()` method is for ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)). Example:

```
class MyData(models.Model):
    some_json = JSONField()
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if not is_my_schema(self.some_json):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid schema.')
```

Comment: But clean method is not call automatically. Right ?

Answer (score 8):

you could use [cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/index.html) to validate your data against a schema

```py
from cerberus import Validator

schema = {'name': {'type': 'string'}}
v = Validator(schema)
data = {'name': 'john doe'}
v.validate(data)  # returns "True" (if passed)
v.errors  # this would return the error dict (or on empty dict in case of no errors)
```

it's pretty straightforward to use (also due to it's good documentation -> validation rules: http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a custom `JSONField` that extends `models.JSONField` and validates attribute's value by using `jsonschema` (Django 3.1, Python 3.7).

I didn't use the `validators` parameter for one reason: I want to let users define the schema dynamically.So I use a `schema` parameter, that should be:

1. `None` (by default): the field will behave like its parent class (no JSON schema validation support).
2. A `dict` object. This option is suitable for a small schema definition (for example: `{"type": "string"}`);
3. A `str` object that describes a path to the file where the schema code is contained. This option is suitable for a big schema definition (to preserve the beauty of the model class definition code). For searching I use all enabled finders: `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.find()`.
4. A function that takes a model instance as an argument and returns a schema as `dict` object. So you can build a schema based on the state of the given model instance. The function will be called every time when the `validate()` is called.

**`myapp/models/fields.py`**

```py
import json

from jsonschema import validators as json_validators
from jsonschema import exceptions as json_exceptions

from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
from django.core import checks, exceptions
from django.db import models
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class SchemaMode:
    STATIC = 'static'
    DYNAMIC = 'dynamic'


class JSONField(models.JSONField):
    """
    A models.JSONField subclass that supports the JSON schema validation.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, schema=None, **kwargs):
        if schema is not None:
            if not(isinstance(schema, (bool, dict, str)) or callable(schema)):
                raise ValueError('The "schema" parameter must be bool, dict, str, or callable object.')
            self.validate = self._validate
        else:
            self.__dict__['schema_mode'] = False
        self.schema = schema
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def check(self, **kwargs):
        errors = super().check(**kwargs)
        if self.schema_mode == SchemaMode.STATIC:
            errors.extend(self._check_static_schema(**kwargs))
        return errors

    def _check_static_schema(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            schema = self.get_schema()
        except (TypeError, OSError):
            return [
                checks.Error(
                    f"The file '{self.schema}' cannot be found.",
                    hint="Make sure that 'STATICFILES_DIRS' and 'STATICFILES_FINDERS' settings "
                         "are configured correctly.",
                    obj=self,
                    id='myapp.E001',
                )
            ]
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return [
                checks.Error(
                    f"The file '{self.schema}' contains an invalid JSON data.",
                    obj=self,
                    id='myapp.E002'
                )
            ]

        validator_cls = json_validators.validator_for(schema)

        try:
            validator_cls.check_schema(schema)
        except json_exceptions.SchemaError:
            return [
                checks.Error(
                    f"{schema} must be a valid JSON Schema.",
                    obj=self,
                    id='myapp.E003'
                )
            ]
        else:
            return []

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if self.schema is not None:
            kwargs['schema'] = self.schema
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    @cached_property
    def schema_mode(self):
        if callable(self.schema):
            return SchemaMode.DYNAMIC
        return SchemaMode.STATIC

    @cached_property
    def _get_schema(self):
        if callable(self.schema):
            return self.schema
        elif isinstance(self.schema, str):
            with open(finders.find(self.schema)) as fp:
                schema = json.load(fp)
        else:
            schema = self.schema
        return lambda obj: schema

    def get_schema(self, obj=None):
        """
        Return schema data for this field.
        """
        return self._get_schema(obj)

    def _validate(self, value, model_instance):
        super(models.JSONField, self).validate(value, model_instance)
        schema = self.get_schema(model_instance)
        try:
            json_validators.validate(value, schema)
        except json_exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(e.message, code='invalid')
```

Usage:
**`myapp/models/__init__.py`**

```py
def schema(instance):
    schema = {}
    # Here is your code that uses the other
    # instance's fields to create a schema.
    return schema


class JSONSchemaModel(models.Model):
    dynamic = JSONField(schema=schema, default=dict)
    from_dict = JSONField(schema={'type': 'object'}, default=dict)

    # A static file: myapp/static/myapp/schema.json
    from_file = JSONField(schema='myapp/schema.json', default=dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using [`jsonschema`](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) for simple cases.

```py
class JSONValidatedField(models.JSONField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.props = kwargs.pop('props')
        self.required_props = kwargs.pop('required_props', [])
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        try:
            jsonschema.validate(
                value, {
                    'schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': self.props,
                    'required': self.required_props
                }
            )
        except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError:
            raise ValidationError(
                    f'Value "{value}" failed schema validation.')


class SomeModel(models.Model):
    my_json_field = JSONValidatedField(
            props={
                'foo': {'type': 'string'}, 
                'bar': {'type': 'integer'}
            }, 
            required_props=['foo'])
```