# Validating polymorphic data in JSONField using json-schemas

Tags: django, polymorphism, jsonschema

Hello Stackoverflowers!

I've searched for a solution for this for a while, but have not been able to find anything addressing this usecase specifically.

Say we have the following models:

```
class Machine(models.model):
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    machine_data_template = models.JSONField()

class Event(models.model):
    machine_name = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    machine_data = models.JSONField()
```

We have a *machine* for which there can be multiple *events*, the details of which are stored as JSON in a JSONField. The JSONField in *event* should be validated using the json-schema defined in Machine.machine_data_template.

I've looked at various Python/Django implementations of json-schemas, however I have not been able to find a way where we can define custom validation on a per-object basis. For example, solutions such as the one presented by Corwin Cole [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642742/django-postgresql-json-field-schema-validation) defines the validation logic directly in the model, which would mean each instance of *event* would be subject to the same validation logic regardless of the *machine*:

```
MY_JSON_FIELD_SCHEMA = {
    'schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'my_key': {
            'type': 'string'
        }
    },
    'required': ['my_key']
}

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_json_field = JSONField(
        default=dict,
        validators=[JSONSchemaValidator(limit_value=MY_JSON_FIELD_SCHEMA)]
    )
```

Does anyone have any suggestion how I can achieve the desired "fully polymorphic" behavior?

BR - K

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [`Model.clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method and add custom validation there. You have access to the `Event` and it's related `Machine` so can access the schema. Add an example using [`jsonschema`](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) similar to the linked answer

```
import jsonschema


class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    machine_data_template = models.JSONField()


class Event(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    machine_data = models.JSONField()

    def clean(self):
        try:
            jsonschema.validate(self.machine_data, self.machine_name.machine_data_template)
        except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            raise ValidationError({'machine_data': str(e)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Iain! I think the approach you outlined will work well, I'll update once I try it out.